# jQuery - .first() versus [0] element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Using jQuery 3.1.1, why are the results of these two different?

```
$('dd[data-something]').first().innerText;
```

^ returns *undefined*

```
$('dd[data-something]')[0].innerText;
```

^ returns valid data

Wouldn't the 0th element of an array also be the .first() element?

**Edit**: Thanks all, I got it, jQuery object versus DOM element.  As the debugger clearly showed before I could delete this :)  That's a clear sign its time to call it quits for the day.

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes about an hour, two tops, and it pays you back that time immediately.

Comment: Note that `$('dd[data-something]').first()[0]` is the same as `$('dd[data-something]')[0]` as well as `$('dd[data-something]').first().first()[0]`. Moreover, `$('dd[data-something]').first()` is the same as `jQuery('dd[data-something]:eq(0)')`. This might help you in understanding when you are dealing with a jQuery object or with a plain element, hopefully :-|

Answer (score 4):

Because [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first) returns a jQuery object wrapped around the first raw DOM element in the set (which has no `innerText` property, but does have that handy [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) method), and `[0]` directly accesses that raw DOM element (which does have an `innerText` property on most browsers).

Answer (score 1):

[`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) will return a jQuery object which is different from the normal JavaScript object and won't work with native JavaScript APIs, here's a qoute from the official documentation

> the .first() method constructs a new jQuery object from the first element in that set.

The second one (index zero) will return a JavaScript object it's almost like calling the element using [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

So if you want to get the text use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) from jQuery and it will work

```
$('dd[data-something]').first().text('new text'); // this will change the text
```